# How to get all terms with services module?

Tags: javascript, services

I am working on an app (react native) and when i make a request to get the taxonomy terms i don't get all the terms

This is the url i used to get the terms:

http://example.io/api/taxonomy_term?parameters[vid]=2&pagesize=1000

But when I go to the url from my browser i get the full list of terms!

Here is my fetch code:

```js
fetch('http://dev-fnyan.pantheonsite.io/api/taxonomy_term?parameters[vid]=3&pagesize=500').then((response) => response.json()).then((response) => {
    let data=[]
    response.map(i =>{
      data.push({label:i.name, value:i.tid, parent:i.parent})
    })
    this.setState({
      categories: data
    })
  }).done();
```

Can anyone suggest where is the problem?

Comment: I guess you are using https://github.com/github/fetch, right? And what do you mean "I don't get all them terms" ? Do you mean you still be able to get some of them?

Comment: Fetch function is built in react. And i get some of the terms not everything, some thing with postman i dont get all the terms in postman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to grant permission for `Perform unlimited index queries` at `admin/people/permissions`. Alternatively, you can set this in `settings.php`:

`$conf['services_taxonomy_term_index_page_size'] = 200;`